# File Uploading ReadAsDataUrl

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a question about the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and uploading files in JavaScript and how I should do this.

I have already utilized a file uploader that was quite simple, it simply took the files from an input and made a request to the server, the server then handled the files and uploaded a copy file on the server in an uploads directory.

However, I am trying to give people to option to preview a file before uploading it. So I took advantage of the File API, specifically the `new FileReader()` and the following `readAsDataURL()`.

The file object has a list of properties such as `.size` and `.lastModifiedDate` and I added the `readAsDataURL()` output to my file object as a property for easy access in my Angular `ng-repeat()`.

My question is, it occurred to me as I was doing this that I could store the dataurl in a database rather than upload the actual file? I was unsure if modifying the File data directly with it's dataurl as a property would affect its transfer.

What is the best practice? Is it better to upload a file or can you just store the dataurl and then output that, since that is essentially the file itself? Should I not modify the file object directly?

Thank you.

**Edit:** I should also note that this is a project for a customer that wants it to be hard for users to simply take uploaded content from the application and save it and then redistribute it. Would saving the files are urls in a database mitigate against right-click-save-as behavior or not really?

Comment: I think it depends on how you are going to use the image. Store the url means you are sure that the url is always accessible, even in another pc  or location. If the url is from another site, then you need to make sure the site never go down, otherwise it will affect your product. From your description, you have people to upload the content and have users to view it, if the file is in local computer, I don't think user will be able to access the file. As for save-as case, as long as the content is displayed in user's browser, I think nothing much you can do to prevent user copy it.

Comment: @Surely I mean the dataurl, that has nothing to do with accessibility from another domain, as I understand its a output of the file as a string.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood it. As long as you have the content, I think it has no problem to store the content directly. You may lose some other information like the filename.. your server also need some change to convert the uploaded data into a file as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is more then one way to preview a file. first is dataURL with filereader as you mention. but there is also the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) which is faster

Decoding and encoding to and from base64 will take longer, it needs more calculations, more cpu/memory then if it would be in binary format.

Which i can demonstrate below

```js
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/ESC_large_ISS022_ISS022-E-11387-edit_01.JPG'


fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {

  // Simulates a file as if you where to upload it throght a file input and listen for on change
  var files = [blob]

  var img = new Image
  var t = performance.now()
  var fr = new FileReader

  img.onload = () => {
    // show it...
    // $('body').append(img)

    var ms = performance.now() - t
    document.body.innerHTML = `it took ${ms.toFixed(0)}ms to load the image with FileReader<br>`


    // Now create a Object url instead of using base64 that takes time to
    // 1 encode blob to base64
    // 2 decode it back again from base64 to binary
    var t2 = performance.now()
    var img2 = new Image
    img2.onload = () => {
      // show it...
      // $('body').append(img)
      var ms2 = performance.now() - t2
      document.body.innerHTML += `it took ${ms2.toFixed(0)}ms to load the image with URL.createObjectURL<br><br>`
      document.body.innerHTML += `URL.createObjectURL was ${(ms - ms2).toFixed(0)}ms faster`
    }
    img2.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0])

  }
  fr.onload = () => (img.src = fr.result)
  fr.readAsDataURL(files[0])

})
```

The base64 will be ~3x larger. For mobile devices I think you would want to save bandwidth and battery.

But then there is also the latency of doing a extra request but that's where http 2 comes to rescue